# Is it safe to unsubscribe from an event that has never been subscribed?

Tags: c#, .net, events, subscribe, unsubscribe

For example, if these codes:

```
        Button button1 = new Button();
        // ...
        button1.Click -= button1_Clicked;
```

are executed before:

```
        button1.Click += button1_Clicked;
```

I found no error or exception, but I am wondering if there is any downside here.

If it is safe, why is it allowed to unsubscribe from an event that has never been subscribed?

Comment: Why would you expect it *not* to be?

Comment: It does not really make sense to me that we could unsubscribe from something before we subscribe to it first.

Comment: Fair enough, but consider a `List<T>`. If you call `list.Remove(new T())`, it won't throw an exception. At most, you'll get a return value of `false` from most C# collection types.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can't find a reference specific to events, but it is documented for the [underlying function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove.aspx) that events use, `Delegate.Remove`:

> Returns source if value is null or if the invocation list of value is not found within the invocation list of source

So it will be safe at least for events that use implicit accessors.

Custom accessors are a whole other ball of wax, as one could implement the `remove` block however you want. I would assume people would mimic the implicit behavior, but this isn't enforced.

Comment: Where could I find this reference?

Comment: MSDN documents [Delegate.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove.aspx)